# Optional argument/param in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have method to which I want to pass an optional argument. By default I want to set that argument as nil. Here is the way I am doing it:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2: nil)
  # Do something
end
```

I call the function as `my_function(2, 5)`. I am getting an error which says:
"wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)"

Am I doing something wrong here? I wish to pass a value for arg2 during some calls and want it to be nil otherwise. So when I don't pass a value for arg2, my function call looks like `my_function(2)`.

Comment: You can also use `my_function(2, arg2: 5)`

Answer (score 2):

Try out

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2 = nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a default keyword argument (vs a positional argument). You can call the function that you've defined with `my_function(2)` as well as `my_function(2, arg2: 5)`. If you would like to use a positional argument you can define it as `def my_function(arg1, arg2 = nil)`

Here are some details on keyword arguments. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments